# Initial CAP After Bullet in UITextView

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, uitextview, capitalization

I think this boils down to whether there is a way to set the shift key to selected state programmatically in a UITextView?

I provide users a key to insert a bullet "•" into the text view, and you typically want to capitalize the character immediately following. As such, I'd like to set the keyboard to shift enabled for the first character typed after the bullet key is tapped. Hopefully this would apply to both onscreen, and external keyboard use cases.

I have already set Capitalization to Sentences on the text view, and it does not address this scenario.

Comment: Follow up: I asked about this at WWDC. According to the engineers I spoke with, there is no way to set the shift key programmatically. I did not find a way to address this scenario.

Comment: Actually this is indeed possible now — see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68436829/15959847).