# UITextView autocapitalization is not working when keyboard is active

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview

Currently, I am setting autocapitalization in a button target like this

```
//This method is fired when keyboard is still active
- (IBAction)changeAutoCapitalization:(id)sender
{   
      self.textView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
}
```

But this won't make keyboard to capital.

Comment: Did you read the documentation ?

Comment: It just auto change the first character of sentence typed in your textview to capital character. It does not change the look of the keyboard (except when you start new sentence, the shift button is ON).

Comment: Use `UITextAutocapitalizationTypeAllCharacters` if you want to switch the keyboard to capital characters only.

Comment: @Hoa I am setting this autoCapitalization property when keyboard is still active(Keyboard is visible) for that UITextView and it is not getting changed.

Comment: ah ok, call `[self.textView reloadInputViews];` after having changed the autocapitalizationtype

Comment: @Hoa It worked ! Thanks for the help.
Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to call `[self.textView reloadInputViews]` after modifying the UITextAutocapitalizationType in order to change keyboard immediately.

Comment: So frustrating that this isn't auto-called by the OS when autocapitalizationType is modified. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this after initialization:

```
self.textView.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```

OR

It's very likely that the "Auto-Capitalization" option is turned off on that device. You can find that option in Settings > General > Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that you're doing a lot of text-related customizations, it might be helpful to subclass `UITextView`, to keep the functionality encapsulated.

> **Note**: If testing on the simulator, make sure you are using the
> Simulator's keyboard, by going to the menu: I/O -> Keyboard -> Toggle
> Software Keyboard

If you are adding text automatically, for instance in response to a button tap, and the shift key turns off, then you can use this pattern:

```
autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters //Activate shift key
autocorrectionType = .no //Don't show all-caps auto suggest
reloadInputViews() //Apply changes
```

Then, to restore to sentences capitalization, for instance when a line is cleared:

```
if (autocapitalizationType = .allcharacters) {
    autocapitalizationType = .sentences //Activate sentence capitalization
    autocorrectionType = .yes //Show auto suggest
    reloadInputViews() //Apply changes
}
```

Other capitalization options:

```
.none
.words
```

You may also need to do this when any non-enter key is pressed. To do so, override `insertText` from `UIKeyInput`, and check the entered text string:

```
if (text != "\n") {
    if (autocapitalizationType == .allCharacters) {
        autocapitalizationType = .sentences //Activate sentence capitalization
        autocorrectionType = .yes //Show auto suggest
        reloadInputViews() //Apply changes
    }

    //Respond to any character sequences
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case I was using **'Keyboard Type'** as Name pad in storyboard.

**Changing 'Keyboard Type' back to 'Default' resolved my issue.**

[image]

Also added this code in **viewDidLoad**

```
textfieldCardName.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
```